# JUnit's MaxCore from ant

Tags: ant, junit

Is there a way to use JUnit 4.6's new MaxCore runner from the  ant task?

Comment: How did you go with this?  We would like to use something like the MaxCore logic from Maven (via surefire), did you have any luck getting this working?

Comment: Nope. I switched to maven with surefire and never looked back!

Answer (score 1):

As of 4.6, unfortunately no.  You'd need to create your own custom Ant task in order to take advantage of the MaxCore functionality.